# a word for "in view of an expected outcome"

Tags: word-choice, british-english

I'm trying to improve my English, and I'm writing a letter which contains the phrase:

> I'm wondering, in ?view? of a positive response, if I could start preparing the project.

My doubt is, given I don't know the outcome, and it's not in "view",  but I simply expect a positive one, the phrase:

> I'm wondering, expecting a positive response, if I could start preparing the project.

sounds really bad, I'm not sure what's wrong but I'm sure it's wrong.

I recall there was an appropriate word to express expectancy, that's why I structured the original phrase that way, but now I can't recall that word, not even in my native language.

Comment: *In view* means that you've received the positive response. After all, you're viewing it. If you haven't received such a response, you can say "in anticipation of a positive response."

Comment: "in anticipation" is good, getting closer.

I would like also to express that I think it will be a positive one, it's like a double opposite of "in spite": in the sense that is a forecast and that is in harmony not in opposition (not sure if I'm helping or creating confusion with this comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Anticipate" would be a great word to use to express the expectancy you're looking to convey in a common, colloquial way.

I might play around with something like this: "Anticipating/assuming a positive response, I am/was wondering if I could start the project."

Anticipate:

verb (used with object), anticipated, anticipating.
1.
to realize beforehand; foretaste or foresee:
to anticipate pleasure.
2.
to expect; look forward to; be sure of:
to anticipate a favorable decision.

Comment: This is so close I'm thinking I must have thought about a word that doesn't exists, or simply mixed a meaning with a wrong word.

I'll play a bit with this, probably it's the appropriate word.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***[anticipation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anticipation)***

> 1. The act of expecting or foreseeing something; expectation or presentiment: "None are happy but by the anticipation of change: the change itself is nothing" (Samuel Johnson).
> 2. An expectation: "His heart was light and his anticipations high" (Mark Twain).
> 3. Action taken in order to prevent or counteract something: The police department's anticipation of unruly behavior after the championship game prevented mayhem.

*(thefreedictionary.com)*

Your sentence:

*I'm wondering whether, in **anticipation** of a positive response, I could start working on the project.*

You could also say *in the hopes of* or *in the expectation* (for this one you'd have to be quite confident.)

(You can also take a look at a thesaurus, now that you've got at least one reasonable candidate word.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was still dubious because I was using a different word and context as a reference, without realizing it.

Also, the "whether" correction is extremely helpful, not having the time to follow a proper course this small helps are invaluable.

Thanks